# Laptop powers off instead of suspending when power reaches critical-battery-level

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, battery

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on System76 laptop.  I am able to successfully suspend the laptop manually.  However, the laptop powers off instead of being suspended when critical battery level is hit.  Has anybody else faced this issue?  If so, how did you fix it?

In gsettings,

- `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-Low/Critical/Action` limits via *gsettings* are set 20, 15, and 10
- `use-time-for-policy` is set to `false`
- `critical-battery-action` is set to `suspend`

In `/etc/Upower/Upower.conf`,

- `PercentageLow/Critical/Action=20/15/10`
- `NoPollBatteries=false`
- `UsePercentageForPolicy` is commented (defaults to false)
- `CriticalPowerAction=HybridSleep`

Comment: Suspend still uses power to keep RAM alive. It is unwise to rely upon suspend below your critical battery level. Shutdown or Hibernate instead.

Comment: True.  I often put it back on the charger after suspension.  So, for now, I'd like to prevent loss of work when I miss to see critical battery notice.